# How to get current route path in Flutter?

Tags: routes, navigation, flutter

While implementing [persistent bottom bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511549/permanent-view-with-navigation-bar-in-flutter), previous [route need to be restored](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10975) when a button in the [bottom bar](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html) was clicked.

When a button in the bottom bar is clicked, its current route path ([/a/b/c](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)) is saved and previously saved route is restored according to the button click.

Conceptually user will think each button as a workspace and its state is never get lost (including back stack). User can safely switch from one workspace to another.

How to get current route path in Flutter, when the routing is [rewinding to root](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popUntil.html)?

Comment: Many things were added in Navigator 2.0: https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade
For new apps consider a whole different design.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

[ModalRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html) should give you the exact route name

```
ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name
```

Note: if you use Navigator.popUntil.. check this other answer out by Rémi Rousselet https://stackoverflow.com/a/50817399/5921185

Comment: Why to you have import of the path package in your sample? Does it have anything to do with the solution?

Comment: It does not return the current route on the navigator

Comment: This doesn't work after using Navigator.popuntil....

Comment: This doesnt work because I am using onGenerateRoute https://stackoverflow.com/a/60103947/7731571 . This can be fixed by passing settings though: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50192#issuecomment-590307455

Answer (score 40):

In case if you want to get current route by use navigator key, possible to use popUntil method for it:

```
String? currentPath;
navigatorKey.currentState?.popUntil((route) {
  currentPath = route.settings.name;
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Perfect answer when using nested navigator key, well play !!!

Comment: I couldn't figure out why all my returned names are null. Then I found out that I needed to pass the 'settings' property when building the routes manually using onGenerateRoute method and returning

MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => YourWidget(),
  settings: RouteSettings(name: "payment")
)

Comment: This is a sweet hack, take my +1

Comment: That is a simple but genial hack!

Comment: @OliverDixon This will not pop routes because function returns true.

Answer (score 31):

`NavigatorState` doesn't expose an API for getting the path of the current route, and `Route` doesn't expose an API for determining a route's path either. Routes can be (and often are) anonymous. You can find out if a given `Route` is on the top of the navigator stack right now using the [`isCurrent`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/isCurrent.html) method, but this isn't very convenient for your use case.

I would recommend that you take a different approach to this problem and don't rewind to the root at all. Instead, use a different `Navigator` widget for each pane of the `BottomNavigationBar`. That way, you won't have to rewind the stack when switching between panes. You can wrap your `Navigator` widgets in [`Opacity`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) and [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) widgets to hide them when they aren't supposed to be visible without destroying their stack.

[image: app video]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class SecurePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  SecurePage(this.index);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      color: Colors.amber,
      child: new InkWell(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Icon(
            Icons.security,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: index * 100.0 + 20.0,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return new SecurePage(index + 1);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class VerifiedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  VerifiedPage(this.index);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new InkWell(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Icon(
            Icons.verified_user,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: index * 100.0 + 20.0,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return new VerifiedPage(index + 1);
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _page = 0;
  List<Widget> initialWidgets = <Widget>[
    new SecurePage(0),
    new VerifiedPage(0),
  ];

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Stack(
        children: new List<Widget>.generate(initialWidgets.length, (int index) {
          return new IgnorePointer(
            ignoring: index != _page,
            child: new Opacity(
              opacity: _page == index ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              child: new Navigator(
                onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                  return new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => initialWidgets[index],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _page,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _page = index;
          });
        },
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.security),
            title: new Text('Secure'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.verified_user),
            title: new Text('Verified'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Beautify. This solution also solve other state problem I am having.

Comment: In fact, I was tinkering around `Stack` and `Opacity`, but not able to get it work. I was not aware `Navigator` can be localised. `IgnorePointer` is another trick I was not able to figure out. Combining the two, a build-in [Hide-Show Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489804/show-hide-widgets-on-flutter-programmatically) will be good, to make them discoverable.

Comment: This fantastic solution has [other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46500186/flutter-keyboard-issue-when-wrap-under-stack-opacity-scrollable).

Comment: @CollinJackson What happens if `IgnorePointer` isn't included? I read the documentation but am still unsure how it relates to the navigation stack

Answer (score 25):

If you are using go_router package you can use the below code :

```
GoRouter.of(context).location
```

Update on go_router 10.0.0 (2023) :

```
GoRouterState.of(context).uri.toString();
```

Comment: If you don't have the context, you can also use the navigatorKey: `final currentPath = GoRouter.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!).location;`

Comment: What's the difference from `uri.toString()` and `routeInformationProvider.value.location`?

Answer (score 15):

Posting this answer mainly for archival purposes, but as @ikben mentioned, one way to get the current route, and all its properties, is `ModalRoute.of(context)`. This returns a [`ModalRoute`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute-class.html), which despite its name, applies to most `Navigator.push` calls, not just `showDialog`. Helpful properties include [`Route.settings`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/settings.html), [`Route.navigator`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/navigator.html), and [`Route.isFirst`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/isFirst.html).

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package version >= 9.0.0:

```
GoRouter.of(context).routeInformationProvider.value.location
```

or

```
GoRouterState.of(context).location
```

Answer (score 5):

I was using **onGenerateRoute** so I also had this issue.
I resolved it by using **NavigatorObserver**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppNavObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  static final navStack = <RouteStackItem>[];

  @override
  void didPop(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    if (previousRoute != null) {
      navStack.removeLast();
    }
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    navStack.add(RouteStackItem.fromRoute(route));
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    if (previousRoute != null) {
      navStack.removeLast();
    }
    super.didRemove(route, previousRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route? newRoute, Route? oldRoute}) {
    if (oldRoute != null) {
      navStack.removeLast();
    }
    if (newRoute != null) {
      navStack.add(RouteStackItem.fromRoute(newRoute));
    }
    super.didReplace(newRoute: newRoute, oldRoute: oldRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didStartUserGesture(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    // TODO: implement didStartUserGesture
    super.didStartUserGesture(route, previousRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didStopUserGesture() {
    // TODO: implement didStopUserGesture
    super.didStopUserGesture();
  }
}

class RouteStackItem {
  final String? name;
  final Object? args;

  const RouteStackItem({
    required this.name,
    required this.args,
  });

  factory RouteStackItem.fromRoute(Route route) =>
      RouteStackItem(name: route.settings.name, args: route.settings.arguments);
}
```

In main.dart

```dart
MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: flavorConfig.appTitle,
              color: AppColors.primary,
              theme: AppTheme.light,
              navigatorObservers: [
                AppNavObserver()
              ],.....
```

Then you can use this to get the current route from anywhere

```dart
   var navStack = AppNavObserver.navStack;
          var routeSettings = navStack.isEmpty ? null : navStack.last;
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using go_router in my project. In go_router, you access current route as below

```
    var currentRoute = GoRouter.of(context).location;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `go_router`:

```
GoRoute(
  name: 'login',
  path: '/login',
  builder: (context, state) => LoginScreen(),
),
```

use this

```
GoRouterState.of(context).path
```

for named routes use:

```
GoRouterState.of(context).name
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using go_router ^11, use

```
router.routeInformationProvider.value.uri
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a much simpler solution. I love StatelessWidget's so I did it with a static, but you can do it with a StatefulWidget.  You'll need a StatefulWidget if you have hierarchical navigation.  This is a tile in my NavDrawer.
(Statics get a bad rap but in a UI it's not bad, there's only one process running a single thread.)

```
class NavListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  static String currentRoute = 'dashboard';
  final String route;

  const NavListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.route,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var isCurrent = currentRoute == route;
    String suffix = isCurrent ? '_green' : '';
    return ListTile(
      title: NavMenuItem(capitalizedRoute, isCurrent,
          "assets/images/" + route + suffix + ".png", context),
      onTap: () {
        currentRoute = route;
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/' + route);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a convenient extension on NavigatorState to get the first route in the stack:

```
extension NavigatorStateX on NavigatorState {

  String? get currentRouteName {
    String? name;
    popUntil((route) {
      name = route.settings.name;
      return true;
    });
    return name;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have `context` available but was able to import the router from the file it was defined in and use like this:

```
router.routeInformationProvider.value.location
```

Comment: In v10 it's: router.routeInformationProvider.value.uri

Comment: I actually noticed a bug with this, it seems like it did't update.  I opened an issue but haven't been able to update it yet with an example so they closed it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
final routeName = Navigator.of(context).widget.pages.last.name;
```

Comment: That's the only solution worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For go_router: >13.0.1

with context:

```
final currentPath = 
GoRouter.of(context).routeInformationProvider.value.uri.path
```

with Global / Navigator Key:

```
final currentPath =  GoRouter.of(goRouterKey.currentContext!).routeInformationProvider.value.uri.path
```

inside GoRouter redirect:

```
GoRouter(redirect: (context, state) {final currentPath =  state.uri.path}
```