# How to check which the current Route is?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to navigate to different Routes using a Drawer, though I do not want to open a new instance of a Route each time I tap on it if I am already on that Route, rather I would prefer that in this case a new Route is not opened. This is my code so far:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Drawer(
      child:
          new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new ListTile(
                title: new Text("NewRoute"),
                onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop;
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/NewRoute');
                }
              )
           )
     )
}
```

I want to use a conditional statement to check whether we are on a certain route. I know there is a way to check which Route we are on currently with the isCurrent of the Route class

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Route/isCurrent.html

though I am not sure how to implement it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using a https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html that keeps the last event and provides it to interested parties could work (not tried myself).

Comment: Interestingly, `RouteAware` methods don't provide the route settings. So you can't know what's the name of the current route with `RouteAware`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current route path in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483949/how-to-get-current-route-path-in-flutter)

Answer (score 91):

`Navigator` doesn't expose the current route.

What you can do instead is use `Navigator.popUntil(callback)` as `popUtil` pass to the callback the current `Route`, which includes it's name and stuff.

```
final newRouteName = "/NewRoute";
bool isNewRouteSameAsCurrent = false;

Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
  if (route.settings.name == newRouteName) {
    isNewRouteSameAsCurrent = true;
  }
  return true;
});

if (!isNewRouteSameAsCurrent) {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, newRouteName);
}
```

Comment: Interestingly when I try you solution (quite smart I would say) I receive:
Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null,
Though I did get it working by bypassing the use of the boolean value by Navigotor.pushNamed(context, NewRouteName); within the first if statement whilst changing the condition to !=.

Comment: did you forget to initialize `isNewRouteSameAsCurrent` to false ?

Comment: I initialized it, though Interestingly enough it seems that even when there is no present boolean value to begin with it still throws the same exception xD

Comment: Did you solve the null boolean exception? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: does this code work with the main route ? route.settings.name returns nothing but `/`  .

Comment: I have an issue that after changing route current route becomes null. Same like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430579/current-route-name-becomes-null-after-pushing-another-route - any ideas?

Answer (score 44):

This should give you the exact route name

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';

ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name
```

To avoid null exception do this

```
var route = ModalRoute.of(context);

if(route!=null){
    print(route.settings.name);
 }
```

Short Way as suggested by @DarkNeuron

> ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.name

Comment: Better way to avoid null pointer exception: `ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.name`

Comment: ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name return me as widget in version 1.17.0 releasebuild. But it working fine on debug build.

Any idea for it ?

Comment: for some reason, Rémi Rousselet's method works for me, but this one always gets null.

Answer (score 25):

You could just use one:

```
Get.currentRoute
```

with this package: https://pub.dev/packages/get

And you would have the current route.

However you wouldn't need this, because unlike the standard Flutter, Get prevents the user from accidentally clicking a button twice (if the user is on a low-cost device it will happen after a jank).
Then you would only need to use: `Get.to(Home());` and ready, it would be done!

Currently, Getx is practically indispensable for projects with Flutter for this reason.
I looked at all the questions, and they are cool, but they usually involve using a popUntil to gain access to the route and this can seem like a hack when another developer reads your code.
With GetX you will not have this double click problem, because it only navigates to another page of the same if you expressly disable it using Get.to(Page(), preventDuplicates: false);
Remembering that this is the exception, in your case you could simply use:
Get.to(Page()); and navigate to the next page without any risk of duplicate routes, because preventing that sort of thing already comes standard on it.

Getting the current route also seems to be something that involves a lot of boilerplate, with Get you get the name of the current route (even if you don't have named routes it will give you the name of it anyway), using a simple: `Get.currenteRoute`.

Well, it's a little late to answer that, but I hope you and other users who read this enjoy

Comment: How to you listen for route changes using the GetX package? Thanks

Comment: Please include a [disclosure about your connection to the project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: returns an empty string for me ;-/

Comment: Reference to "cool questions" doesn't improve your answer. If "Get" can find "current route" (or "path" in Web App) then one can write code doing this using standard Flutter features. [if "get" has such code, then it is "doable" writing such code]

Answer (score 14):

This is a perfect use case for Dart extension methods (based on Rémi Rousselet's answer):

```
extension NavigatorStateExtension on NavigatorState {

  void pushNamedIfNotCurrent( String routeName, {Object arguments} ) {
    if (!isCurrent(routeName)) {
      pushNamed( routeName, arguments: arguments );
    }
  }

  bool isCurrent( String routeName ) {
    bool isCurrent = false;
    popUntil( (route) {
      if (route.settings.name == routeName) {
        isCurrent = true;
      }
      return true;
    } );
    return isCurrent;
  }

}
```

Then it looks as clean as this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedIfNotCurrent('/NewRoute');
```

Comment: lates flutter 1.20.2 throws error ambiguous_extension_member_access
you should use different extension name for ex extension MyNavigatorStateExtension on NavigatorState {
and use it this way MyNavigatorStateExtension.of(context). pushNamedIfNotCurrent

Comment: route.settings.name is always null

Answer (score 10):

[Rémi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50817399/8340797) really helped me, but if you're new to Flutter/Dart like me, it takes a while to understand. So here's a my version with some extra checks and explanatory documentations:

```
/// Navigates through the application. Only replaces the top Route if it is
/// different from the new Route. Always keeps the home page as base of the
/// Navigator stack. New screens are pushed on the Navigator stack. When the
/// user switches between non-home screens, the new screen replaces the old
/// screen. In this way, the stack of screens from the drawer is never higher
/// than 2. Returning to the HomeScreen is done by just popping the current
/// Route.
void _changeRoute(BuildContext context, String newRouteName) {
  // Close drawer
  Navigator.pop(context);

  // Check current screen status
  bool currentRouteIsHome = false;
  bool currentRouteIsNewRoute = false;

  Navigator.popUntil(context, (currentRoute) {
    // This is just a way to access currentRoute; the top route in the 
    // Navigator stack.
    if (currentRoute.settings.name == HomeScreen.ROUTE_NAME) {
      currentRouteIsHome = true;
    }
    if (currentRoute.settings.name == newRouteName) {
      currentRouteIsNewRoute = true;
    }

    // Return true so popUntil() pops nothing.
    return true;
  });

  // Switch screen
  if (!currentRouteIsNewRoute) {
    // Only switch screen if new route is different from current route.
    if (currentRouteIsHome) {
      // Navigate from home to non-home screen.
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, newRouteName);
    } else {
      if (newRouteName == HomeScreen.ROUTE_NAME) {
        // Navigate from non-home screen to home.
        Navigator.pop(context);
      } else {
        // Navigate from non-home screen to non-home screen.
        Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, newRouteName);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this implementation with `pushNamed` and `popAndPushNamed` requires you to define `Route` names in your top level `MaterialApp` in the `routes:` argument, like so:

```
new MaterialApp(
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    // define the routes
    YOUR_SCREEN_ROUTE_NAME: (BuildContext context) => new YourScreen(),
  },
)
```

Comment: How is this called if the user taps the back button?

Comment: @TimSim Use `WillPopScope` widget for registering back button press.

Comment: Looks a bit crazy just for switching pages in a mobile app...

Comment: @Kirill well you could also choose to use a single Scaffol and update its body based on the state of the Drawer, but code is if you want to use the built-in Routes in combination with the Drawer

Comment: currentRoute.settings.name is always null

Comment: @Zeeshan Mehdi make sure the input parameter of your Anonymous function has the same name (currentRoute).

Answer (score 5):

```
ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name
```

is a good API to solve this problem but this can't be used in initState();

Comment: It is a comment, not answer. Please write something more, otherwise, it will be closed soon.

Comment: you can use it inside @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {}

Comment: I think you're slightly wrong about not being able to use ModalRoute inside initState(); You can simply use Future.delayed method with a duration as minimum as 1 millisecond. Inside the callback of Future.delayed, you can comfortably use ModalRoute

Answer (score 4):

Based on Rémi Rousselet answer.

```
String? currentPath;
navigatorKey.currentState?.popUntil((route) {
  currentPath = route.settings.name;
  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution. Based on the Rémi Rousselet solution.
The only difference is that prevent te pop of the "last" route remaining.

```
bool routeFound = false;
String routeName = "/myRoute";

//remove all the routes and stops if find the routeName or if is the last one
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
    if (route.settings.name == routeName) {
        expenseRouteFound = true;
    }
    //print("route " + routeName + " founded in stack: " + routeFound.toString());
    //print("last remaining route into the stack: " + route.isFirst.toString());

    return routeFound || route.isFirst;
});

//print("route " + routeName + " founded in stack: " + routeFound.toString());
if (!routeFound) {
    //print("time to push the route: " + routeName + "!");
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(routeName, (_)=>false);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution.

```
void redirect(screen){
  Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
    if ( route.settings.name != screen) {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, screen);
    }
    return true;
  });
}
```

Comment: route.settings.name is always null

Answer (score 1):

Am using this code.

```
*Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Myinternet());
 print(route.isCurrent);
 if(route.isCurrent){
 }*
```

**Output:**

> **Shows** Always **false** current page not finding

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to check if route is top most ...

```
 Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WidgetName());
 if(route.isCurrent){
 }
```

Comment: Widgets don't have access to the route. You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

for me i'm using the laziest easiest way since no answer here helped me in main route, i just use drawer class and pass the name of the current route to the drawer constructor like this :

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
final String currentRoute;
MyDrawer(this.currentRoute);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Drawer(
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
            child: Text('secondRoute'),
            onTap: () {
              if (currentRoute != 'secondRoute')
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => secondRoute()));
            }),
        InkWell(
            child: Text('thirdRoute'),
            onTap: () {
              if (currentRoute != 'thirdRoute')
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => thirdRoute()));
            }),
```

and in the routes where i call MyDrawer class i pass the name of the current route

```
drawer: MyDrawer('secondRoute'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the router:

```
Router.of(context).routeInformationProvider?.value.location
```

Answer (score -2):

In Getx stateManagement, Just use `Get.currentRoute`.

```
print(Get.currentRoute);
```

Output :

```
flutter: /ScheduleOrBookNowScreen
```