# How to avoid duplicate screen on top in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Giving that I have declared my routes in MaterialApp of my flutter application, now I am using

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,ScreenA);
```

now on some user event I need to open ScreenA but only if ScreenA is not there already otherwise just update arguments in that ScreenA.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data). You can await a result from all the pages you open from Screen A and use the values returned from these pages in Screen A once you pop back to it

Comment: Actually use case is ScreenA is a screen main screen which has materialApp now screenB got open due to user button click and then via deepLink screenA tries to open ScreenB again, hence this logic will not help me. WDYT?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current top screen and set your condition like below,

```
final newRouteName = "/NewRoute";       // Here add your route name 
bool isNewRouteSameAsCurrent = false;

Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
  if (route.settings.name == newRouteName) {
    isNewRouteSameAsCurrent = true;
  }
  return true;
});

if (!isNewRouteSameAsCurrent) {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, newRouteName);
}
```

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50817399/11427294).

Comment: Actually use case is ScreenA is a screen main screen which has materialApp now screenB got open due to user button click and then via deepLink screenA tries to open ScreenB again, hence this logic will not help me.  Aprt from this above one will be fired from context of screenA hence it will clear ScreenA and not ScreenB

Comment: This makes sense when you are routing by using same screen context else it will show the name of the screen from which context is used