# Hero Animation not working inside nested Navigator

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to use Hero Animations in my first flutter app, but there is already instagram like bottom navigation, that implemented using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46498543/10184844) approach, and I found that Hero Animations just doesn't work inside nested Navigators.

For example you can get **Complete example** from [here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/hero-animations/) and replace `home: MainScreen(),` from `HeroApp` class to

```
home: Navigator(onGenerateRoute: (_) {
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MainScreen());
}),
```

and hero animation will break.

Maybe there is some another approaches to implement bottom navigation with independent stacks for each tab, that don't use nested navigators, but I haven't found any.

So any advice much appreciated.

UPD: I just realized that answer should be in `MaterialApp` class and bingo!

There is naive solution that works:

```
home: Navigator(
  onGenerateRoute: (_) => MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MainScreen()),
  observers: [HeroController()],
),
```

But in `MaterialApp` source code things are little more complicated, so maybe there are some hidden things, that broke my naive solution. Therefore question is still open.

Comment: You shouldn't nest `Navigator` to begin with

Comment: @RemiRousselet hm, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46498543/10184844) answer (actually made by engineer from Flutter team) proposes `Navigator` nesting. How should I implement bottom navigation with independent stacks for each tab then?

Comment: `Navigator` doesn't support well nesting, as it breaks a few things such as Hero; which are directly associated to a navigator instance. That answer is quite old; depending on what you want there may be better way to achive your need.

Comment: Hi @RémiRousselet the Navigator class documentation has a section on 'Nesting Navigators'. Will Hero animations always break in this case?

Comment: @Mikhail Is it working with your examples above?

Comment: @Mikhail: Also would like to know whether this solution works for you. It doesn't for me.

Comment: @Mikhail, THANK YOU So much!!! I have been wondering for a LONG period of time WHY Hero animation doesn't work in nested navigators. I have viewed a LOT of examples on multiple tabs running at the same time and truly all of them have their own navigators (to keep track of its own stacks) and your solution with a simple line of code simply fixes everything and animations work now! I would've given you 1000 pts for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is because [Hero](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Hero-class.html) relies on a [HeroController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HeroController-class.html) which the navigator in [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) has but your custom one does not, to fix this just add the controller, like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  HeroController _heroController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _heroController = HeroController(createRectTween: _createRectTween);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      observers: [_heroController],
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: settings, builder: (context) => Text(''));
      },
    );
  }

  RectTween _createRectTween(Rect begin, Rect end) {
    return MaterialRectArcTween(begin: begin, end: end);
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider refactoring this to use the [`HeroControllerScope`](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/hero-controller-scope) widget.

Answer (score 5):

August 2022 Update:

A better solution to the accepted answer is to wrap each of your Navigator widgets in a HeroControllerScope widget as shown.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        // Builds two parallel navigators.
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            HeroControllerScope(
              controller: MaterialApp.createMaterialHeroController(),
              child: Navigator(
                onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                  return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                    settings: settings,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return const Text('first Navigator');
                    }
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            HeroControllerScope(
              controller: MaterialApp.createMaterialHeroController(),
              child: Navigator(
                onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                  return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                    settings: settings,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return const Text('second Navigator');
                    }
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Navigator 2.0.

Comment: This is very close to a working solution, but you should typically create the HeroController as a final variable in the state of your widget.