# Flutter: How to use Routes to route between pages when using a wrapper

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am building an app that has multiple pages. The problem is that I have a lot of `Hero()` widgets that I would like to animate between pages. I tried using the animation package's `PageTransitionSwitcher` but `Hero()` widgets don't animate with that. I have a wrapper at the root of my tree below the `MaterialApp()` and I route to either a log in screen, verification screen, and a home screen. The problem is if I route on the home screen it will replace the wrapper so I have resorted to having the home screen be an empty container that pushes a route above it which are the actual home screens, each having a bottomNavigationBar() that pushes a replacement to change screens with a fade animation while `Hero()`s animate.

The problem is that this approach is quite janky and I ran into a lot of problems because I have to have an empty widget that pushes a route then pop all routes in the wrapper when the auth state of the user changes. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this or a way to get route animations without actually routing the user.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: The current approach I had didn't work as it would randomly pop the pages when the user would update their profile. I have temporarily reverted back to the `PageTransitionSwitcher()` but I would like to know how I can use the navigator or use the Navigator's animation with my current setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by nesting Navigators. returning a `Navigator()` in the home page and adding a `HeroController()` (see more here [Hero Animation not working inside nested Navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760916/hero-animation-not-working-inside-nested-navigator)) should do what I was trying to achieve.

You will also need to give the navigator a key and assign a `navigatorKey` in the Material App and route using `keyName.currentState!.push()` for example.