# Flutter StreamSubscription not stopping or pausing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my Flutter app `StreamSubscription` is not pausing or cancelling. When I call `cancel()` if it started before, it will stop. If I call `cancel()` after starting, it will not stop. I am using Firestore snapshot listener. Below is my code.
I have tried different methods but it's still not working. The problem is that the Firestore `listener` is not stopping after loading data.

```
    StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> streamSubscription;

    @override
    void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
        print("Creating a streamSubscription...");
        streamSubscription =Firestore.collection("name").document("d1").collection("d1")
            .snapshots().listen((data){
                //It will display items
            }, onDone: () { // Not excecuting
                print("Task Done");
            }, onError: (error) {
                print("Some Error");
        });
         streamSubscription.cancel(); //It will work but cancel stream before loading
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
     streamSubscription.cancel(); //Not working
    super.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: `stream.close()` should be `stream.cancel()` and a `StreamSubscription` should rather be called `streamSubscription` or `subscription` instead of `stream` because that's quite confusing because a `Stream` is something else entirely.

Comment: There is no `close()` in https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html so it is not surprising that it does not work. If you get an error message you should post that error message with your question.

Comment: I have edited my question. I am using 'cancel()' not close. Sorry for mistake happen.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer did u know why it is not stoping?

Comment: Hard to tell. Perhaps because the events are emitted sync and therefore emitted before `cancel()` is called. Your question is not clear enough about what's actually happening and what the expected behavior is instead. If you could improve that it would rise probability that you'll get a helpful answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer when I am going to another page that listener is not stoping. It is executing new page and interrupting another listeners. I have add cancel in dispose() it is not cancelling and executing new page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189118/discussion-between-joe-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 4):

When you push a new page, the previous page is still rendered and therefore `dispose()` is not called.

- [How to get current route path in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483949/how-to-get-current-route-path-in-flutter)

Also sometimes it can happen that the widget is not rendered anymore but `dispose` was not yet called, which can lead to weird error messages. So adding such a check is probably a good idea as well if you use `dispose`.

- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html

Change

```
//It will display items
```

to

```
if(myIsCurrentRoute && mounted) {
  //It will display items
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the subscription into the right variable.

```
StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

    print("Creating a streamSubscription...");
    subscription=Firestore.collection("name").document("d1").collection("d1")
        .snapshots().listen((data){
            //It will display items
        }, onDone: () { // Not excecuting
            print("Task Done");
        }, onError: (error) {
            print("Some Error");
    });


     subscription.cancel(); //It will work but cancel stream before loading



}

@override
void dispose() {
 subscription.cancel(); //Not working
super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: That is the mistake in my question. I change my question. I assigned in. correct the subscription in right variable. Please again check question and check your answer.

Comment: @Joe Have you tried if the dispose function is being called at all? Try printing something inside the dispose function and see if it is being called.

Comment: I have tried in `dispose()` my dispose() is working but not cancelling the listen. I also called   before calling new screen. `Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()));`

Comment: Can someone please tell me why onDone is not executing here ?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem and it turns out that the stream seems to keep listening for events for a while before canceling, but if you debug you will see that after dispose is called it will stop listening at some point. 
Therefore, [Gunter's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54901093/7606929) solution works fine, since you can prevent your callback function from being called if mount is false, which means your page is no longer there.