# How to get current route name in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, routes

I am a recent flutter developer. How can i get current route name?I am having a common list view in two different routes. I want to hide certain properties in list based on routes.

Please help me..

Comment: this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483949/how-to-get-current-route-path-in-flutter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this:

```
var route = ModalRoute.of(context);

if(route!=null){
  print(route.settings.name);
}
```

Comment: why it returns null ?

Comment: May you write in false place. Put it as chlid of scaffold

Comment: I found that it returns null because I don't use names in routes

Answer (score 0):

path:

```
Router.of(context).routeInformationProvider?.value.location
```

name:

```
ModalRoute.of(navKey.currentContext).settings.name.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get.currentRoute`

is a good solution.