# Difference between onGenerateRoute and routes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the benefit or use case of `onGenerateRoute` and routes in Flutter.

In my application in first page inside `MaterialApp` we can define routes for our Application the same thing we can define with `onGenerateRoute`.

Both are used for NamedRoute.

I am unsure, in which scenario I need to use routes and in which scenario I need to use `onGenerateRoute`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### NB (see comments below answer):

> There is no bug, just bad usage by the issue reporter. **It is caused because he didn't pass the settings object along to the new MaterialPageRoute returned by the onGenerateRoute method** (see the issue's final comments). [...]

---

#### Original answer mentionning a "bug":

Without diving into any details those two properties do the same thing, but as @Alireza noted `routes` is checked first.

Also, using `onGenerateRoute` gives you a single place to add your custom business logic before pushing new routes (pages). For example, if you want to do some initializations.

[routes property:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/routes.html)

> When a named route is pushed with Navigator.pushNamed, the route name
> is looked up in this map. If the name is present, the associated
> WidgetBuilder is used to construct a MaterialPageRoute that performs
> an appropriate transition, including Hero animations, to the new
> route.

[onGenerateRoute property:](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onGenerateRoute.html)

> The route generator callback used when the app is navigated to a named
> route.
> ...
> This is used if routes does not contain the requested route.

**IMPORTANT:**
What you really want to be aware of is a [known bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50192) in `onGenerateRoute` property.

The problem is that if you use `onGenerateRoute` to create named routes you won't be able to get the name of that route from RouteSettings object in your page. (Arguments attached to the settings object are fine though)
In other words:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name == null;       //bug
    ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments != null;  //ok
    ...
```

This may affect you in case you would like to know the name of the current route.
For example, if you want to pop some screens:

```
navigator.popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('/login'));
```

Therefore, until this problem is resolved, I recommend using the `routes:` property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer brother. I have one doubt. that is when we write code for application we can know which are the pages available in our application. so we can mention everything in routes itself. Then why we need onGenerateroute property?

Comment: That bug you mention is not a bug, just bad usage by the issue reporter. It is caused because he didn't pass the settings object along to the new MaterialPageRoute returned by the onGenerateRoute method (see the issue's final comments). I just tested it with flutter 1.12.13 and it works just fine. Besides that, and contrary to what you say, in that issue it had the settings.arguments null as well, and not just the settings.name. Consider changing your answer to instead of mentioning a bug, alerting to the need to pass the settings to the new MaterialPageRoute returned by the onGenerateRoute.

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a feature Sir.

Answer (score 38):

`routes` is static and doesn't offer functionalities like passing an argument to the widget, implementing a different `PageRoute` etc, which is why `onGenerateRoute` exists.

In the given code, you'll find that how using `onGenerateRoute` property, you can parse an argument and send it over, which isn't possible with simple `routes`.

`FooPage` is navigated through `routes` and `BarPage` through `onGenerateRoute`.

---

Initial setup in `MaterialApp`.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (_) => HomePage(), // You can also use MaterialApp's `home` property instead of '/'
        '/foo': (_) => FooPage(), // No way to pass an argument to FooPage.
      },
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        if (settings.name == '/bar') {
          final value = settings.arguments as int; // Retrieve the value.
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => BarPage(value)); // Pass it to BarPage.
        }
        return null; // Let `onUnknownRoute` handle this behavior.
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

`home.dart`:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('HomePage')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/foo'),
              child: Text('Go to FooPage'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/bar', arguments: 42), // Passing argument
              child: Text('Go to BarPage'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`foo.dart`

```dart
class FooPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(_) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('FooPage')));
}
```

And `bar.dart`:

```dart
class BarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  BarPage(this.value);

  @override
  Widget build(_) => Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('BarPage, value = $value')));
}
```

---

**Screenshot (for reference)**

[image]

Comment: Can you also show an example of BarPage as StatefulWidget, thx?

Comment: @cwhisperer Just convert your `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget` and access `value` field using `widget.value` in the state class.

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation (I put the link below), onGenerateRoute is used if routes does not contain the requested route.

[Flutter onGenerateRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onGenerateRoute.html)

Answer (score 6):

My solution is to reassign the settings of MaterialPageRoute, e.g.:

Batch processing:

```
final routes = {
  '/': (context) => MainPage(),
};
```

Routing settings:

```
var onGenerateRoute = (RouteSettings settings) {
    final String name = settings.name;
      final Function pageContentBuilder = routes[name];
      if (pageContentBuilder != null) {
        if (settings.arguments != null) {
          final Route route = MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: settings,
              builder: (context) => pageContentBuilder(context, arguments: settings.arguments));
          return route;
        } else {
          final Route route =
              MaterialPageRoute(settings: settings,
                  builder: (context) => pageContentBuilder(context));
          return route;
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of defining routes.

1. **routes**: where we define static route map to navigator table.

   pros: it effectively able to use the Modal Route

```
    ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments
```

2. **generatedRoutes**:   it is dynamic routing, we can define business login in this, to pass arguments from route settings.

   cons: we cant use ModalRoutes to pass arguments... we have to pass the arguments in constructor.(bug mentioned in above)

```
    static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
     
      switch (settings.name) {
        case AppRoutes.componentDetails:
          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => ComponentDetailsView(arguments: settings.arguments));
    
        default:
          return _errorRoute();
      }
    }
```