# Flutter if current page opens already then on click prevent it from reopening

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I have a problem,
I defined a footer page then its has 3 page to open on click,
I want if current page opens already then how to prevent it from reopening.

[This is My UI buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59qkO.png)

On CLick

```
             InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const ContactUsWindow()));
                  },
```

Comment: Can you include code-snippet

Comment: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const ContactUsWindow()));
                  },

Comment: It need some logic to find the current active page

Comment: but how it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ModalRoute`, [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54962054/10157127)

```dart
 InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      final currentRoute  =    ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name;
      if(currentRoute != "ContactUsWindow"){ //here ContactUsWindow your current route
          Navigator.push(.......
```