# How to use multiple navigators

Tags: dart, flutter

I currently have a `MaterialApp` in my flutter application which makes the use of the `Navigator` extremely easy, which is great. But, I'm now trying to figure out how to create more navigators for particular views/widgets. For example I've got a custom tab bar with another widget/view in. I'd now like that widget/view to have it's own navigation stack. So the goal is to keep the tab bar at the top while I navigate to other pages from within my widget/view.
This question is almost exactly this: [Permanent view with navigation bar in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511549/permanent-view-with-navigation-bar-in-flutter) but in that code, there is no `MaterialApp` yet. Nesting `MaterialApp`s give funky results and I don't believe that that would be a solution.
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create new Navigator for each page. As a reference check [CupertinoTabView](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/9909e773dc66608a866efa7388f39127509d0e1e/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/tab_view.dart)

Or simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Navigator _getNavigator(BuildContext context) {
    return new Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return new Center(
            child: new Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(settings.name),
                new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, "${settings.name}/next"),
                  child: new Text('Next'),
                ),
                new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () =>
                      Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: new Text('Back'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: _getNavigator(context),
          ),
          new Expanded(
            child: _getNavigator(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Home(),
  ));
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I actually know about the `TabView` but that's not what I meant. I'd actually like to have a navigation stack for each tab page in my tabbar, any idea how that can be accomplished?

Comment: One more question, when I'm in my second level navigator (So the one not created by my `MaterialApp`) how can I make the back button work? It just closes the app for me :/

Comment: @BramVanbilsen, if it's your own button, check what Navigator you use. You should take the "second" one, not "main". If it's scaffold's button, make sure scaffold is placed in scope of "second" Navigator.

Comment: Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483949/how-to-get-current-route-path-in-flutter).

Comment: @Mogol Woops, should have mentioned that I was talking about the hardware Android back button. Any idea about that?

Comment: I guess you can take a look [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBinding/handlePopRoute.html)

Comment: How can I push something to the „root“ navigator when iam in the scope of another navigator? Navigator.of targets the closest navigator that encloses the given context, not the root navigator. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use GlobalKey for root navigator. E.g. check answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303441/flutter-redux-navigator-globalkey-currentstate-returns-null

Comment: @Chris you can access the root navigator like this: Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)

Answer (score 0):

you could give `first material app's context` to `secondary material app`;
and in `secondary material app` ,when you need to go back `first material app`,
you could check whether the secondary app can pop, with this line:

```
 Navigator.of(secondaryContext).canPop()
```

if true, then you could keep using,else use `first material app's context`,
like this:

```
Navigator.of(parentContext).pop();
```

otherwise