# Pass data to multiple screens with inheritedwidget

Tags: flutter, inherited-widget

There are some confusions about `InheritedWidget` that I don't understand.
I have searched and read some QAs about `InheritedWidget` on **stackoverflow**, but there are still things that I don't understand.
First of all, let's create a scenario.
This is my `InheritedWidget`:

```
class MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  final String name;
  MyInheritedWidget({
    @required this.name,
    @required Widget child,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyInheritedWidget oldWidget) =>
      oldWidget.name != this.name;

  static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInheritedWidget>();
  }
}
```

and this is `MyHomePage` that contains the `MyInheritedWidget`. `MyInheritedWidget` has two children: `WidgetA` and a button that navigates to another screen, in this case `Page1`.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: MyInheritedWidget(
          name: 'Name',
          child: Column(
            children: [
              WidgetA(),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Page1(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Go to page 1'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside `WidgetA` there is a text widget that displays the **name** field from `MyInheritedWidget` and another button that navigates to `Page2`.

```
class WidgetA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WidgetAState createState() => _WidgetAState();
}

class _WidgetAState extends State<WidgetA> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myInheritedWidget = MyInheritedWidget.of(context);
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(myInheritedWidget.name),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Page2(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text('Go to page 2'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`Page1` and `Page2` each has only a text widget that displays the **name** field from `MyInheritedWidget`.

```
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myInheritedWidget = MyInheritedWidget.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 1'),
      ),
      body: Text(myInheritedWidget.name),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myInheritedWidget = MyInheritedWidget.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
      body: Text(myInheritedWidget.name),
    );
  }
}
```

In this scenario, the **name** field of `MyInheritedWidget` is not accessible form `Page1` and `Page2`, but it can be accessed in `WidgetA`.

Now lets get to the question:
It is said that an `InheritedWidget` can be accessed from all of its descendants. What does descendant mean?
In `MyHomePage`, I know `WidgetA` is a descendant of `MyInheritedWidget`. but, is `Page1` also a descendant of `MyInheritedWidget`?
If the answer is no, How can I make `Page1` a descendant of `MyInheritedWidget`?
Do I need to wrap it again inside `MyInheritedWidget`?
What if there is a chain of navigations like this: **Page1**-> **Page2** -> **Page3** ... **Page10** and I want to access `MyInheritedWidget` in **Page10**, Do I have to wrap each of the pages inside `MyInheritedWidget`?

Comment: *"[...] but, is Page1 also a descendant of MyInheritedWidget?"* - no `Page1` is not a descendant of `MyInheritedWidget` - `Page1` is a descendant of main `Navigator`

Answer (score 1):

As @pskink says, `MyHomePage` pushes `Page1`, which is a descendant of `Navigator`, which is under `MaterialApp`, not `MyInheritedWidget`. The easiest solution is to create `MyInheritedWidget` above `MaterialApp`. This is my code (using `ChangeNotifierProvider` instead of `MyInheritedWidget`).

```
void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(DevConnectorApp());
}

class DevConnectorApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final log = getLogger('DevConnectorApp');
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthService>(
          create: (ctx) => AuthService(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<AuthService, ProfileService>(
          create: (ctx) => ProfileService(),
          update: (ctx, authService, profileService) =>
              profileService..updateAuth(authService),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<AuthService>(builder: (ctx, authService, _) {
        log.v('building MaterialApp with isAuth=${authService.isAuth}');
        return MaterialApp(
```

Here is an example using multiple `Navigators` to scope the `InheritedWidget`. The widget `ContextWidget` creates an `InheritedWidget` and a `Navigator` and has child widgets for the screens in your example.

```
class InheritedWidgetTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new InheritedWidgetTestState();
}

class InheritedWidgetTestState extends State<InheritedWidgetTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ContextWidget('First'),
            ContextWidget('Second'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  Navigator _getNavigator(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return new Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return child;
        });
      },
    );
  }

  final name;
  ContextWidget(this.name);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyInheritedWidget(
      name: this.name,
      child: Expanded(
        child: _getNavigator(
          context,
          PageWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        WidgetA(),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Page1(),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text('Go to page 1'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: *"The easiest solution is to create MyInheritedWidget above MaterialApp"* - i think its better to use [MaterialApp.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/builder.html) but i agree, the result is the same

Comment: @Patrick I know that wrapping the `MaterialApp` inside `MyInheritedWidget` makes it accessible globally. But I want it to be accessible to only to some part of my app.

Comment: I guess you could make additional `Navigators` for the different parts of your app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502751/how-to-use-multiple-navigators for a discussion of that approach, though it is not about and does not mention `InheritedWidget`.

Comment: I added example code for the multiple `Navigators`.