# Flutter navigation to TabNav page from other page

Tags: flutter

I have a bottomNavigation Bar with a TabBarview as below:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      //drawer: _drawer,
      appBar: new AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: new Text(_choice.title), actions: getAppBarActions(context)),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
          color: CupertinoColors.lightBackgroundGray,
          //color: c,
          child: new Container(
            height: 50.0,
            child: new TabBar(
              controller: controller,
              //labelColor: Colors.grey,
              tabs: mytablist,
              labelStyle: new TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
              labelColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
              unselectedLabelColor: CupertinoColors.inactiveGray,
              isScrollable: true,
              indicatorWeight: 1.0,
              indicatorColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
              //indicatorPadding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
            ),
          )),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: _tabWidgets(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have of courses pages that are navigated to, I also navigate to pages off the tabbarview that do not have the bottomnavigation, however I want to be able to navigate to one of the pages within the bottomnav, but when I do using something like this:

```
Navigator.of(context)..pushReplacementNamed(Chat.ChatServerPage.routeName);
```

It goes to the page but without the appbar or the bottomnavigationbar, anyone know how to accomplish this?  I have tried all that I could find. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the widget referenced by the route return a new Scaffold? A simple way to `DRY` is to make an a parent widget that takes that returns a new Scaffold with the TabBarView and AppBar.

Comment: The page referenced in the route does return a new Scaffold, but if I also tell it to have an appbar and tababr, then when it is called normally through the tabnav then it has 2 appbars and 2 bottom navigation tabnav's because it normally already gets it from the material app

Answer (score 0):

Check your widgets hierarchy. Usually `MaterialApp` widget is top level and it contains `Navigator` widget. That's why "navigation" replaces entire screen.

You could use different ways to implement this:

1. Each page has it's own `Scaffold` with AppBar and NavBar. [Related  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511549/permanent-view-with-navigation-bar-in-flutter/45517670#45517670)
2. It's possible to have multiple navigators. And separate Navigator could be added in Scaffold body. [Related  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46502751/how-to-use-multiple-navigators/46503109#46503109)